# CSS - Allow font to overlow with negative margin

Tags: javascript, html, css, contenteditable

I am creating a code editor using contenteditable and would like to add some syntax highlighting as a background color for all span element. I am using a negative margin to compensate for the border of the element (not shown in the following example, as it is irrelevant to the question). Here is the problem: Using a negative margin on an inline element clips the text at the end, like this:

[image]

I have tried **cannot** use the following, as it messes with my editor in some browsers:

- Pseudo elements
- position: absolute

Here is a code example of the text being clipped:

```css
span{
  margin-left: -20px;
}


/* For visualization only */

* span:first-child{
  background-color: red;
}
* span:last-child{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>

<span>Hello world</span><span>Hello world</span>

</div>
```

If anyone knows how to achieve this without using the aforementioned techniques it would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: The following is an illustration of the desired outcome. This might look like an undesirable effect, but it does make sense in the context of my project.

[image]

Comment: I *assume* since you have javascript as a tag that using JS is acceptable, is that correct?

Comment: A JavaScript solution would also be okay, but CSS is of course preferable. Edit: I should probably mention that I do not want to change the size of the element or create any children. It should just overflow visually without manipulation of the DOM.

Comment: The outcome is actually not what is shown in the photo. Set the opacity of the `span` to something like 0.5 to see it. A negative margin doesn't clip the elements.

Comment: @BehRouz Interesting, so I guess it's the second element hiding the first, not the first element being clipped. I still don't know how to fix this though if I want to use a non-transparent background color.

Comment: Do you want to use nested spans?

Comment: And does `display:inline-block` works for you?

Comment: @BehRouz The only solution would be plain CSS (or even JavaScript) solution without additional elements/DOM manipulation or even pseudo elements since this would cause problems with contenteditable.

Comment: I tried `display:inline-block`, but it does not change this "overlapping" behavior.

Comment: Why do you want to rely on overflow in the first place?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I want the text to appear seamlessly with the background color marking the different elements. It is not illustrated very well in my simplified example; I did my best to show that I want the **text** to overlap, but the **background** to mark the individual elements.

Comment: Could you please create a picture of the desired effect?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Added it to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope somebody will come up with something better

```css
.item {
  transform: translateX(10px);
  display: inline-block;
}

.wrapper:first-child {
  background-color: red;
  box-shadow: 10px 0px 0px red;
  z-index: 10;
}

.wrapper:last-child {
  background-color: yellow;
  box-shadow: 10px 0px 0px yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="wrapper">
  <span class="item">Hello world</span>
  </span>
  <span class="wrapper">
  <span class="item">Hello world</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Using transform is a great idea! Will try to adopt it for my use case (without the wrappers) and will accept your answer when I can.

Answer (score 0):

This is the first thing that came up to me. you can wrap them in another span and use gradient background. You can adjust the percentage of the gradient color on yoru desired percentage.

```css
span.wrapper {  
background: rgb(249,246,0);
background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(246,2,2,1) 44%, rgba(249,246,0,1) 44% ); 
  }
```

```html
<div>
<span class="wrapper">
<span>Span 1</span><span>Span 2</span>
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This unfortunately does not fix the problem with the second span hiding the preceding span, as was explained to me in the comments.

Comment: got it didint see your edit. let me edit my aswer for you.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for this is to manipulate the width of the element.

```js
const spans = document.querySelectorAll('span');
spans.forEach(span => {
  span.style.width = span.offsetWidth - 20 + 'px'
  span.style.marginRight = '20px'
});
```

```css
span{
  display: inline-block;
  overflow-x: visible;
  white-space: nowrap;
}


/* For visualization only */

div span{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>

<span>Hello world</span>
<span>Hello world</span>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I really don't get what you are up to, but using `padding: 0 20px;` (i.e. padding on the sides by the amount you use for negative margin-left) for the first `span` makes all text visible:

```css
span{
  margin-left: -20px;
}


/* For visualization only */

* span:first-child{
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
* span:last-child{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>

<span>Hello world</span><span>Hello world</span>

</div>
```